# change values of dataframe except indices in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of indices of a dataframe and I want to change values of a column of all rows which are not in the list.

This is what I try:

```
df.ix[~idx,'column1'] = 0
```

However I get this error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'list'
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html#pandas.Index.difference) on the index against the row labels you want to exclude and pass this to `loc`:

```
In [108]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[108]:
          a         b         c
0  0.759272 -1.633137  2.193676
1 -0.249800  0.092365 -1.947792
2 -0.601363 -0.171465  0.136735
3  0.242762 -1.406402  0.197774
4 -1.135406 -0.298128  2.234334

In [109]:
idx = [1,3]
df.loc[df.index.difference(idx),'a'] = 0
df

Out[109]:
          a         b         c
0  0.000000 -1.633137  2.193676
1 -0.249800  0.092365 -1.947792
2  0.000000 -0.171465  0.136735
3  0.242762 -1.406402  0.197774
4  0.000000 -0.298128  2.234334
```